# Can I enable file removal in the open window on OS X?

Tags: finder, filesystem, defaults

Can I enable file removal in the open window on OS X?

The open or save dialogs do not allow you do do many opeations, like removing a file or renaming it.

Is there any hidden `defaults` preference that could enable this?

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/release.html) (35$) for years to add this capability, among many others.

Comment: An excellent product from an excellent (and long standing) developer.